# Supported locations for window.onerror to work?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Does window.onerror need to be in the head section of the current page being loaded?

I have this code (Chrome 64.0.3282.140, linux):

```
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript">
     window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
       alert(errorMsg + lineNumber);
       // alert("This is a stack trace! Wow! --> %s", error.stack);
     };
   </script>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">
  //var x=document.getElementById("demo").value; //uncomment and run to see
  document.write('careless to close the parentheses?'; // ')' is not given
</script>
```

which works wonderfully if the window.onerror is in the head of the page, but if I move it out of the `<head></head>`, it stops working. And if I try to move it into a `.js` file, it also stops working.

Is there any way to set the `window.onError` outside `<head>` or another way to globally catch errors from outside the head, and preferably in a separate `.js` library file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be sure that the `window.onerror` file has to be first code to be executed.

And that is why you put it in `head` works.

You can put it in the body and put other scripts behind it or put other script code in the

```
window.onload=function(){
//other code
}
```

demo below is put them in the body and `window.onerror` is the first script

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    alert(errorMsg + lineNumber);
    // alert("This is a stack trace! Wow! --> %s", error.stack);
  };
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
  //var x=document.getElementById("demo").value; //uncomment and run to see
  document.write('careless to close the parentheses?'; // ')' is not given
</script>
```